# 2D Arrays: Retrieving Row/Column and not value

Tags: java

I'm wishing to compare an array with itself, so it doesn't process a certain body of code unless the coordinates are different. For example:

```
if (one [a][b] == two [c][d]) 
{
    //Do Nothing
}

else 
{
    System.out.println(one [a][b]);
}
```

What I want to do is to compare the coordinates used ([a][b] and [c][d]), and not the value of what the element of one or two is. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: as in `if (a==c || b==d) { /* nothing */ } else { /*something*/}` ? or even `if (a != c && b != d) { /*something*/ }` - do both have to be different, or just one?

Comment: Sorry I should clarify. Let me put values in place of the variables I used. 
`code` if [50][50] == [50][50]
{
    //Do Nothing
}

else
{
    //Something if [50][50] != [c][d]
}`code`

Comment: If you don't care about the values in the array, then it doesn't make sense talking about array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just check indicies, why not just do that? Just make a pair of variables for one array say: arrOne_col and arrOne_row, and then do the same for the other and compare their values.